# Gensim LDA logging not displaying

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook, gensim

I am currently training an LDA model in gensim and would like to know if the model is converging or not. Unfortunately I get no logging output. The relevant code looks like this:

```
from gensim.models.ldamodel import LdaModel
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logging.root.level = logging.INFO
model = LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=id2word, num_topics=6, random_state=0, chunksize=100, alpha='auto', per_word_topics=True, iterations = 100, passes = 2, eval_every=1)
```

When I use this: `logging.info("hello world")`
this works fine however in my jupyter notebook. If anybody had an idea how I could get the logging output from gensim, I'd be really gratefull.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it should work. Could you try placing the `import` of `LdaModel` **after** the global logging configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, gojomo. Unfortunately, it's still the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with DEBUG logging (INFO worked though). I solved it by manually removing handler from the logging object:

```
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
   logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
```

Maybe it will work also for fixing INFO logging.