# Cannot see DEBUG logs for “number of documents converged“ info when running Gensim's LDA suggested for choosing iterations and passes

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda

In official [Gensim tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_lda.html) there is a mention about how to set number of iterations and passes:

> I suggest the following way to choose iterations and passes. First, enable logging (as described in many Gensim tutorials), and set eval_every = 1 in LdaModel. When training the model look for a line in the log that looks something like this:

```
2016-06-21 15:40:06,753 - gensim.models.ldamodel - DEBUG - 68/1566 documents converged within 400 iterations
```

I've never saw anything like this line in my LDA logs though. [Those are my logs on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/eyKsEuZK). I've folowed the [official tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_lda.html).

I'm alllowing debugging like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO,
                            filename='content_based_algorithms/training_logs/lda/logs.log')
```

I even tried to explicitly define callbacks::

```
perplexity_logger = PerplexityMetric(corpus=corpus, logger='shell')
convergence_logger = ConvergenceMetric(logger='shell')

lda_model = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics, passes=passes, alpha=alpha, eta=eta, update_every=1, eval_every=1, callbacks=[convergence_logger, perplexity_logger])
```

I've tested that both in Windows, PyCharm IDE and Ubuntu command line execution of Python cript.

**Possible duplicate with the post [Gensim LDA logging not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69269058/gensim-lda-logging-not-displaying/73002839#73002839)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

> DEBUG - 68/1566 documents converged within 400 iterations

Can be obtained in the logging file changing the logging configuration to *debug* in you case would be something like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',
                   level=logging.DEBUG,
                   filename='content_based_algorithms/training_logs/lda/logs.log')
```

Now the line will appear inside the logging file.

Answer (score 0):

I marked as the answer [the response of user1649814](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72492681/4183655) because he is correct that the missing `level=logging.DEBUG` parameter was the main flaw, thus he deserves it. However, for the people dealing with the same problem, I want to point out, that even after the change to `level=logging.DEBUG`, DEBUG logs haven't appeared in my case. What solved my problem was to include:

```
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
   logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
```

before the logging settings.

I also changed `level` to: `level=logging.NOTSET` so I include both INFO and DEBUG (and also warnings etc...).